# How can I implement Afterpay in Flutter? Couldn't find any guide / package

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment

We've implemented Paypal,
Braintree and now we want to implement Amazon pay and Afterpay.
We found some packages for amazon pay but couldnt find anything for Afterpay and Flutter.
We'd really appreciate if someone can guide us.
I think it can be implemented like paypal using webview.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no official package right now.

how about try to use the direct api using `http` or `dio`

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final String baseUrl = 'https://api.us.afterpay.com/v2/checkouts';
final String merchantId = '<your-merchant-id>';
final String secretKey = '<your-secret-key>';

Future<http.Response> createOrder(double amount, String currency, String 
                      reference) async {                        

 Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
                                    "amount": {
                                           "amount": "100.00",
                                           "currency": "USD"
                                             },
                                    "mode": "express",
                                    "merchant": {                                     
                                 "popupOriginUrl":"https://www.afterpay-merchant.com/cart"
                                              }
                           };
           return await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
           headers: {'accept': 'application/json','Content-Type':'application/json'},
           body: jsonEncode(requestBody));
     }
```

from the **Response** you have to handle success or fail and save the order id for future use and reference.

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't work like this